# Snowflake Gui - Just Shows Tables and Views

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-webui

On the left part of the web interface for Snowflake, it shows me databases, schemas, tables, and views.

Is there a way to show functions that were created in a schema, or does it just show tables and views?

Comment: Getting Started With the Snowflake New Web Interface

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-gs.html#getting-started-with-the-new-web-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the new snowsight has this :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the various "SHOW ..." commands to see these objects

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can view the definition of a function by using either of the following commands in the query interface:

```
SELECT GET_DDL('function', <function_name(argument_datatype)>');
```

or:

```
DESC FUNCTION <function_name(argument_datatype)>;
```